# Python How do you loop through a list of strings that contain variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with some data and building a list of queries based upon what `incident_source`.  This was working fine when I didn't have variable added to it which requires the + symbols.  When I added that I am getting: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`.  Does anyone know a way around this or a better solution?

```
source = 1
offense_id = [122,153,142]
incident_source = ['source_1', 'source_2']
num_searches_by_id = []
queries_needed_ran = []

for i,j in zip(incident_source, offense_id):
    if i == 'source_1':
        data = ['''SELECT QIDNAME(qid) AS 'Event Name',"Request Method" FROM events WHERE URL=REPLACEFIRST('hxxp',''' + "'" + source + "'" + ''','http') START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''',
                '''select QIDNAME(qid) as 'Event Name', "Recepient" from events where ( "URL"=''' + "'" + str(source) + "'" + '''AND logSourceId='1' ) START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''']
        num_searches_by_id.append(len(data))
        for x in data:
            queries_needed_ran.append(x)
            
    elif i == 'source_2':
        data = ['''select QIDNAME(qid) as 'Event Name', "Recepient" from events where ( "URL"=''' + "'" + str(source) + "'" + '''AND logSourceId='1' ) START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''']
        num_searches_by_id.append(len(data))
        for x in data:
            queries_needed_ran.append(x)
    else:
        num_searches_by_id.append(0)


runfile('/Users/thomas.gorman/Documents/Python Connectors/riskiq_passivetotal/untitled20.py', wdir='/Users/thomas.gorman/Documents/Python Connectors/riskiq_passivetotal')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/me/Documents/Python Connectors/untitled20.py", line 427, in <module>
    data = ['''SELECT QIDNAME(qid) AS 'Event Name',"Request Method" FROM events WHERE URL=REPLACEFIRST('hxxp',''' + "'" + source + "'" + ''','http') START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''',

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`
```

Expected output:

```
num_searches_by_id = ['''SELECT QIDNAME(qid) AS 'Event Name',"Request Method" FROM events WHERE URL=REPLACEFIRST('hxxp',''' + "'" + source + "'" + ''','http') START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''',
                '''select QIDNAME(qid) as 'Event Name', "Recepient" from events where ( "URL"=''' + "'" + str(source) + "'" + '''AND logSourceId='1' ) START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''',
'''select QIDNAME(qid) as 'Event Name', "Recepient" from events where ( "URL"=''' + "'" + str(source) + "'" + '''AND logSourceId='1' ) START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''']
```

Comment: What is `source`? And what is your expected output?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is an input that actually causes the error, and what is the full traceback of the error you encounter? The bit of the error you posted implies that your input is a list, rather than a string in a list, at the point the error occurs.

Comment: source = 1 @PacketLoss

Comment: @G. Anderson My question is, I can loop through a list that does NOT contain a '+ <variable> +', but when I add a '+ <variable> +', I get a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: Ah.. you seem to want `source` to indicate the `source` specified in the list. You can access this via `i` which you defined in the opening of your loop.

Comment: By the way, you should not construct your SQL queries by hand like this.  You should be using ? substitution, letting the database do the quoting.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you.  I will have to look if Qradar can handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure about some of your variables and where they are coming from, but I got rid of the `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str` by placing brackets for the index your looking for in your `if` statement and changing the variables. Also not sure where `start_time` is coming from...

```
offense_id = [122,153,142]
incident_source = ['source_1', 'source_2']
num_searches_by_id = []
queries_needed_ran = []

for i,j in zip(incident_source, offense_id):
    if i == 'source_1':
        data = ['''SELECT QIDNAME(qid) AS 'Event Name',"Request Method" FROM events WHERE URL=REPLACEFIRST('hxxp',''' + "'" + incident_source[0] + "'" + ''','http') START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''',
                '''select QIDNAME(qid) as 'Event Name', "Recepient" from events where ( "URL"=''' + "'" + str(incident_source[0]) + "'" + '''AND logSourceId='1' ) START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''']
    num_searches_by_id.append(len(data))
    for x in data:
        queries_needed_ran.append(x)
        
    elif i == 'source_2':
        data = ['''select QIDNAME(qid) as 'Event Name', "Recepient" from events where ( "URL"=''' + "'" + str(incident_source[1]) + "'" + '''AND logSourceId='1' ) START ''' + str(start_time) + '''-43200000''']
        num_searches_by_id.append(len(data))
        for x in data:
            queries_needed_ran.append(x)
    else:
        num_searches_by_id.append(0)
```

Comment: I totally get it now.  So before it was working fine with queries without variables from a list.  Now that its pulling data from a list I way trying to pass that list as a string.  WOW.  should have been using the index of the list as a string :).  Thank you!

Comment: No worries. I put the actual value for you to see, but @PacketLoss is correct that you could simply pass `i` due to your conditional. Also, Qradar should be able to handle the SQL constructions if you are using their API